# получение уникального пути для загрузки файла в django

Tags: django

добрый день, у меня есть модель такого типа:

```
class Campain(models.Model):
    Company_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'ICO'),
        ('2', 'Invest'),
    )

    upload_path = 'static/presents/'    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_('Тип кампании'), choices=Company_CHOICES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('Название 
    presentation = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, verbose_name='Файл презентации проекта', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    biography = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Описание проекта и команды'))
    steep = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    activate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Компания')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Компании')
```

хотелось бы получить каким нибудь образом `self.title` для нормального складирования файлов, что бы путь к файлу выглядел `upload_path = 'static/{}/spresents/'.format(self.title)`, но я не понимаю как это сделать, можете подсказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего, не надо ничего загружать в static. Этот каталог, как следует из его названия, для статики. Динамику надо грузить в media. А чтобы получать сформировать путь загрузки в момент загрузки, [в upload_to можно передать функцию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
from os import path
from django.conf import settings

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'presentations',
                     instance.title, filename)


class Campain(models.Model):
    ...
    presentation = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to,
                                    verbose_name='Файл презентации проекта',
                                    validators=[validate_file_extension])
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо, все получилось, вопрос закрыт!